# How to remove a tween before moving to next frame in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip which spins. I want it when users drag and drop it to stop spinning and be in it's initial position. I wrote this code but i get error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at omoixes10_fla::MainTimeline/EntFrame() when I move to next frame. I can not see what i did wrong. Can you please help me with my code? Do I have to remove tween before I move to next frame?

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;


tick1.parent.removeChild(tick1);
wrong1.parent.removeChild(wrong1);

sentences2.buttonMode=true;
sentences1.buttonMode=true;
Piece1_mc.buttonMode=true;

var my_x:int=stage.stageWidth
var my_y:int=stage.stageHeight
var myWidth:int=0-my_x;
var myHeight:int=0-my_y;
var boundArea:Rectangle=new Rectangle(my_x, my_y, myWidth ,myHeight);



var spin:Tween=new Tween(Piece1_mc, "rotation",Elastic.easeInOut,0,360,5,true);
    spin.stop();



sentences2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    snoopy.gotoAndPlay(2);
    addChild(tick1);
    addChild(wrong1);
    sentences2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
    sentences1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  fl_MouseClickHandler_2);
    spin.start(); 
    spin.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
    function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {
     e.target.yoyo();

    {
     Piece1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, DragP1);
     function DragP1 (event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        Piece1_mc.startDrag();
        Piece1_mc.startDrag(false,boundArea);
        spin.stop();
    }

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, DropP1);
    function DropP1(event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        Piece1_mc.stopDrag();
    }
    if(Targ1_mc.hitTestObject(Piece1_mc.Tar1_mc)) {
        Piece1_mc.x=677;
        Piece1_mc.y=48,10;
        myTimer.start();
    spin.stop();
    }
    }
}


sentences1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    snoopy.gotoAndPlay(64);
}


var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000,1);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void {
gotoAndStop(15);

 if (Piece1_mc.parent)
      {
         Piece1_mc.parent.removeChild(Piece1_mc);
      }if (tick1.parent)
      {
         tick1.parent.removeChild(tick1);
      }
    if (wrong1.parent)
      {
         wrong1.parent.removeChild(wrong1);
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: You are adding event listeners inside an Enter frame. This would keep adding event listeners at every frame! That would never lead to good results :( Move your drag event listeners outside the enter frame. On a side note, why do you need an Enter Frame event if all you are doing is adding drag and drop events?

Comment: Thank you, you are right but there  must be more mistakes in my code because when i remove event listeners inside an Enter frame my hitTestObject does not work.

Comment: Add a mouse move listener when your drag starts, and check your hit test inside the mouse move event listener and completely remove the enter frame as it's not needed. Remember to remove the mouse move listener when your drag finishes or whenever your hit test is successful.

Comment: I correct it. It works. Now the only problem is to have my spinning movieclip in its initial place when users clicks to drag it.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the latest code and I'll have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. i updated my code. See above.

Comment: I've added an answer. Please see if it works for you and feel free to accept it as the right answer if it does. Thanks!

Comment: My code still comes up with some problems but with the help you gave me i will solve them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So the first problem was adding your event listeners inside an enter frame which was not the right way to do since it will keep on adding event listeners at every frame.

Second, you should use a mouse move event listener as I've recommended before to track and test your hit test.

Thirdly, since you are rotating your MovieClip, and you want it to go back to its initial state, you should do :

```
Piece1_mc.rotation=0;
```

Hope this helps.